How to inject button virtual DOM webpages?
I am new to chrome extension development. I want to add a button on a webpage, into a part of the webpage which is re-rendered every time the user clicks on any link on the webpage.
E.g.
Consider a react page. The page is divided into two parts, where one part contains multiple links and other part contains a div which has content. My button is rendered on top of the content but inside the div. When user selects a certain link, the content changes. Basically the content div is re-rendered.
I am able to inject the button into the content div, but once the user selects a different link, the button disappears.
How do I make this work?
I am building the chrome extension with Manifest v3 in React TypeScript while the content-script is TypeScript.
I tried to add a listener to the targetDiv and listen to the changes to its children, however, that does not seem to work.
function observeTargetDivChanges(targetDiv: HTMLElement) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                if (document.querySelector('.button-insert-div-class')) {
                    insertNewButton();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    observer.observe(targetDiv, {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
}

const targetDiv = document.querySelector('.target-div-class') as HTMLElement;
if (targetDiv) {
    observeTargetDivChanges(targetDiv);
} else {
    console.log('Target div not found.');
}



If you declare the content script in manifest.json then it probably runs before the target element is created, so try observing document.body. 2) You need to reload the extension after you edit files in content_scripts and re-inject them after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome. 3) Remove mutations.forEach(function (mutation) { and if (mutation.type === 'childList') {

